# How to view files uploaded from minIO S3 on local machine?

Tags: minio

I'm studying about minIO.

My question is that, If I upload a file through the minio console, I can check the uploaded file in the directory on my local machine.
However, It is not the same file that I uploaded, but a part file in the form of an object.
(File name becomes a folder name)

Is there a way to get the same file in my local machine which I uploaded through minIO console?

I need your help.
Thank you.

[image]